# PHP function error Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

Shortly I need to block a group of users at once according to their role status (banned or not) instead of blocking users one by one.
I tried using fk on update cascade to control the role status by making a fk user_role_status column in the users table refers to role_status column in the roles table but without luck because when I change a role status in roles table it changes the whole user_role_status column in users table not only the role I changed then it blocks all users not only the group I want to block because role_status in roles table is not unique and I can't make it unique because its all cells contain value='1', so I deleted the column and gave up that idea

```
// role_status in roles table is a fk refers to id in statuses table.
 
    statuses_table
    
    id       is_active              
    ------------------
    0          no                        
    1          ok                        
    
    roles_table
    
    id       role              role_status
    --------------------------------------
    1        Admins                1
    2        Editors               1
    3        Users                 1
    
    users_table
    
    id       user_name       user_level       
    ---------------------------------------
    1        Admin               1                                 
    2        Editor1             2                                  
    3        User1               3                                  
    4        Editor2             2                                 
    5        User2               3                                   
    6        User3               3
```

and this is the function I use

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Find role status
--------------------------------------------------------------

function find_by_current_rolStatus($role_status)
{
global $db;
$sql = "SELECT users.id FROM users JOIN roles ON roles.id = users.user_level WHERE roles.role_status = '{$db->escape($role_status)}'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
return($db->num_rows($result) === 0 ? true : false);
}
    
--------------------------------------------------------------
Function for checking if user role status banned or allowed
--------------------------------------------------------------
    
function login_require_roleStatus($require_role_status)
{
global $session;
$current_user = current_user();
$current_user_role_status = find_by_current_rolStatus($current_user['role_status']);//line 155
//if Role status Deactive
if ($current_user['role_status'] === '0')://line 157
$session->msg('Banned');
redirect('home.php',false);
//if user role allowed
elseif($current_user['role_status'] === '1')://line 161
return true;
endif;
}
```

and I got this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: role_status in sql.php on line 155
Notice: Undefined index: role_status in sql.php on line 157
Notice: Undefined index: role_status in sql.php on line 161
```

Comment: Hi - your data model seems to be a bit confused. In your roles table the id and role level seem to be duplicates so I’m not sure why you need both columns. User_level appears to be an FK to role_level whereas I’d expect an FK to reference the PK in the related table. user_role_status is a duplicate of role_status so your model doesn’t appear to be properly normalised. If you fix all these issues then most of the problems you are facing would go away - and you wouldn’t need much of the functionality you seem to have built

Comment: @NickW , I got it, I will delete the role_level and use the id to avoid dublication and check if this will solve the issue or not.

Comment: @NickW, well, I did what you said but it the same unfortunately.

Comment: Please update your question with the DDL for the current design of the two tables, including any PKs/FKs, constraints, etc

Comment: Also, I’m not sure why you’ve introduced the status table as it appears to add no additional value. You also have still not normalised your model correctly as role_status/user_role_status is still duplicated across 2 tables

Comment: @NickW , I updated the question inside the code area // user_role_status in users table is a fk refers to role_status in roles table and role_status in roles table is a fk refers to id in statuses table.

Comment: @NickW , The problem here is that I can't make the role_status column a unique key because all of its values are duplicated ('1') by default, and in the same time I need to make it a reference key of the user_role_status.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure should be like this

```
status_table

id       is_active              
------------------
0        no                        
1        ok                        

roles_table

id       role              role_status
--------------------------------------
1        Admins                 1
2        Editors                1
3        Users                  1

users_table

id       user_name       user_level      
------------------------------------
1        Admin             1        
2        Editor1           2        
3        User1             3        
4        Editor2           2        
5        User2             3        
6        User3             3
```

Where, `roles_table.role_status` will refer to `status_table.id` and `users_table.user_level` should refer to `roles_table.id`

This way you will be able to  perform your task whenever you want to check user role status you just need to fire this query

```
select roles_table.role_status from users_table, roles_table where role_table.id = users_table.user_level and user_table.id=2
```

This way whenever you change the role_status in role_table you will be able to determine it's status without `on update cascade`

you can learn more foreign key concepts for mysql [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Do you mean that I can delete the user_role_status column from the users table ?? I will try this. and tell you what happened.

Comment: @NaderHussein yes you can delete that column it's not necessary it's just not normalised.
on the go you should learn [normalisation](https://www.javatpoint.com/dbms-normalization) you will understand the concepts more

Comment: It didn't work because of undefined index .. And this is the function I use
`function login_require_roleStatus($require_role_status){
     global $session;
     $current_user = current_user();
     $current_user_role_status = find_by_current_grpStatus($current_user['role_status']);
      //if Role status Deactive
    if ($current_user['role_status'] === '0'):
          $session->msg('Banned');
          redirect('home.php',false);
          //if user group allowed
      elseif($current_user['role_status'] === '1'):
        return true;
        endif;
     }`

Comment: In the `find_by_current_grpStatus` I used your SQL SELECT query..
and the errors I got are
Notice: Undefined index: role_status in sql.php on line 155

Notice: Undefined index: role_status in sql.php on line 157

Notice: Undefined index: role_status in sql.php on line 161

Comment: Please update your question with additional information, rather than adding it in comments - for one thing it allows you to format code so it is readable. Please add the code for functions login_require_roleStatus and find_by_current_grpStatus to your question and then include the error message

Comment: In find_by_current_rolStatus you are passing in the role status value but then comparing it to the user id, which doesn’t make sense to me. When you’ve assigned $current_user to current_user(), why do you think $current_user['role_status'] would work? Current_user() is returning a value from your system, why would it know about a role_status attribute you’ve defined in one of your tables?

Comment: @NickW , I changed the query to `SELECT users.id FROM users JOIN roles ON roles.id = users.user_level WHERE roles.role_status = '{$db->escape($role_status)}'` , I am trying to get the users whose user_level = role_id which its status = '0' or '1', I checked this SQL query with phpmyadmin and it is working fine, and actually I don't know what to do after that :( , I mean I don't know what to write with $current_user['role_status'] instead of role_status to get what I want.

Comment: @NaderHussein bro the error you are showing in your updated question is about `$current_user['role_status']` because they can't find `role_status` in `$current_user` variable you should see your `current_user()` function may be it is returning the wrong value you should change the question and show the `current_user()` function too.also there are lot of other problems but we can go step by step because i don't think you will understand in one go. also from the look of your code i think you have just started with `PHP`.